# Continuity of $x (\sin (x^2))^2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Prove $x (\sin (x^2))^2$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.

My proof is below.  Can you please verify, critique, or improve?

1. **Continuous**.  $g(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = x^2$ are both continuous, and, given continuous $g$ and $h$, both $g \cdot h$ and $g \circ h$ are continuous.
2. **Not Uniformly Continous**.  $f$'s amplitude grows without bound, while its period vanishes, so it cannot be uniformly continuous.  More formally, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x = \sqrt{\pi n}$, and $f(x) = x$ for all $x = \sqrt{\pi n + \pi/2}$.  For any $\delta > 0$, there exists $m$ such that $n > m \implies |\sqrt{\pi n + \pi/2} - \sqrt{\pi n}| < \delta$. Similarly, to state the obvious, for any $\epsilon$, there exists $r$ such that $x > r \implies x > \epsilon$. Thus, for any $\delta > 0, \epsilon > 0$, there exists $x_0, x_1$, such that $|x_1 - x_0| < \delta, f(x_0) = 0, f(x_1) = x_1 > \epsilon$.  QED.

Comment: How did you get $f(x)=x^2$ for that specific x value? $\sin(x^2)=1$ at that x value so $f(x)=x*(1)^2=x$.

Comment: Fixed.  It was a careless error, but the proof is unaffected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is fine, although here are some small critiques.

First, the sentence "Similarly..." does not seem to play any role in the proof. Also, the preceding sentence introduces an irrelevant variable $m$. So I would replace those two sentences by "For any $\delta > 0$ there exists $n$ such that $|\sqrt{\pi n + n/2} - \sqrt{\pi n}| < \delta$" (you should be prepared to defend that statement by proving the existence of $n$, depending on your intended readership). Then immediately follow it with your last sentence.

You could also be more explicit with your last sentence by writing out how to specify $n$, $x_0$ and $x_1$, something like this: "Choose $x_0 = \sqrt{\pi n}$ where $n > $ [whatever quantity is needed to guarantee that $x_1 = \sqrt{\pi n + \pi/2} > \epsilon$, so I guess $n > \left(\epsilon^2 - \pi/2 \right)/\pi$]".

Also, while I do like proofs that start with an intuitive explanation before diving into the logical details, your opening intuitive sentence didn't make any sense to me: What is the amplitude of $f$? What does it mean to say that the period of $f$ vanishes? I was puzzled by that sentence, but eventually ignored it and went on to read the rest of the proof. Afterwards I could go back and see what you kinda/sorta meant in that opening sentence.

Comment: Thank you.  "For any $\delta>0$ there exists $n$ such that $|sqrt{\pi n + n/2} - sqrt{\pi n}| < \delta$" is insufficient, because perhaps that $n$ is too close to zero.  Hence, I introduced $m$ to show that _all_ $n > m$ have that property.  If you disagree, please elaborate.

Comment: Re the intuitive explanation: I'm surprised that this took away, because I actually edited in after first writing the formal proof, and thought it added a lot.  How would you convey the intuitive argument? (I tried writing it in terms of local maxima growing without bounds, local minima remaining fixed at zero, and x-distance between maxima and minima vanishing, but couldn't get something clear and correct which captured the intuition any better than "amplitude" and "period".)

Comment: Regarding $n$, it's a natural number (perhaps that should be said in the proof but perhaps also its clear by context) and given $\delta > 0$ any natural number $n$ that satisfies the inequality $|\sqrt{\pi n + n/2} - \sqrt{\pi n}| < \delta$ would work for the rest of the proof.